# Blank space at bottom of Wordpress Homepage

Tags: html, css

I just finished working on the Homepage of this site and then I found that on all the other pages there is no space bellow the footer but on the Homepage there is quite large space.

I took out the entire sidebar just for the homepage but it should show on the other pages so I simply added  just before the "secondary" div and finished the "if" after the closing tag of the secondary div but this is not the cause of the problem, I removed the "if" and it remains the same.

The only thing that I can think about is something in the content of the homepage but can't find what it is.
I want the bottom of the page exactly after the footer on all pages including the homepage, anyone finds the problem?

The link:
http://www.israelijewel.com/websites/mishne-torah/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is coming from this element.

```
<map name="simple"></map>
```

You seem to have a load of `<br>` tags inside it not sure why just remove them or you could hack it some more and do `display: none`.

Comment: So it was indeed the breaks inside the map code, I don't know why they were there because I didn't create this map, just implemented it into the homepage. Now that all the breaks are gone its perfect!

Answer (score 0):

It's the `map` element inside of `.map-wrapper`. Adding `map br {display: none;}` in the console seems to clear it up. Presumably that's in a WP Admin content box and it's "helpfully" adding the BR tags for you.

You can also stop wordpress from adding the BRs to a particular post(s). Here's a plugin that does it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/toggle-wpautop/

or in your functions.php, something like this should work.

```
function ij_wpautop_correction() {  

    if( is_page('123') ) { //123 == your page id        

        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

        remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );          

    }

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ij_wpautop_correction');
```

Comment: You did help a bit, I first checked if it is indeed adding to the css your suggestion and once I could see it fixed I used Kyle's suggestion to remove the <br> tags in the map which is a part of the content of the homepage.

Comment: @Will I down voted since this was a duplicate of my answer, also `<br>` tags in a map `element` is not valid.

Comment: Cheers, @KyleNeedham I appreciate the explanation. I hit post before I saw your answer. Sadly, hard to get around the auto-inserted BR madness sometimes in a CMS situation like WordPress. I just added some code to fix it if it is WordPress admin driven (vs hard coded in the template).

Comment: @Will nice one, but I firstly turned off wpautop in the settings of "ultimate tinymce" plugin, but also I turned off the "visual" part of the pages editor since I couldn't find how to stop it from taking my nicely ordered and make it all in one line.
Whenever I want to edit a page's content which is html that I made before in several lines to make it easy, wp visual editor makes the code one line and later it is harder to edit.